# Why can't I log in to PuTTY as user, but only root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ip, putty

I'm trying to Split and format Disk on VM in Debian. I also need set file permision.

My problem is that I can't log to the server through PuTTY as user, only as root. I entered same IP address as for root, password for user also correct.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Sign to SSH as username@ip
2. In Debian edit PermitRootLogin yes

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How do I know to which OS I am connecting to?I've just find my IP adress through cmd promt in Windows and just copied to column for IP adress.I hope I've helped you,I'm new in PC system.

Comment: No,no no.I just checked right IP adress.I am trying to connect to Debian(VM)